# Is it possible to resume fsck.ext4 using offset X?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, fsck

I was fscking my HDD, when I had to stop because I needed to get somewhere within an hour. The whole session took quite a while (lasted much longer than I thought!). My question is, is it possible to pick up from where I left off (block #20211712)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to start a filesystem check operation "in the middle" as the program needs to know the complete state of the filesystem in order to be able to work.

You could have typed ^Z to stop the program and later run `fg` to resume it or just leave it alone. If you killed the program, it is too late to do anything that a complete new run.

Answer (score 1):

in case you only need to look for bad blocks, you can call `badblocks` directly. From the manual:

> first-block is an optional parameter specifying the starting block number for the test, which allows the testing to start in the middle of the disk.

the problem with this answer is: I havent tried it so I cant suggest a safe command.

fsck does call badblocks program.

you can use the bad blocks result with this fsck option later

> -l bad_blocks_file   Add to badblocks list

Obs.: anyone feel free to edit this with a safe command/way to use badblocks :)