# is it possible to `fsck` for badblocks a single LVM logical volume SEGMENT?

Tags: lvm, fsck

why? to [resume](https://askubuntu.com/a/1118819/46437) `fsck -fcck` while looking for badblocks as it takes humongous time (1TB SATA HD) and I have no no-break on my desktop, so, I could split the logical volume in several segments of 10GB and fsck each one per day :)

`kvpm` only gives a popup `fsck` command for the whole logical volume, not the specified segment.

can such check be forced even if in some more complex way?
may be temporarily referencing the segment by separating it from the logical volume it is currently part of, like it being part of another LV just for that check?

Of course that a direct way to force resume `fsck` from a specified block would suffice [if possible at all](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229056/30352).

PS.: I cant suspend the desktop machine, it never works. If if it could work, it would still prevent me from using the main/root volume for a huge long time :(

Comment: Have you considered SMART checks?

Comment: @roaima the disk I want to check currently has 51 bad/pending sectors from smart data at `gnome-disks`. Do you mean that specifically looking for bad blocks is not really necessary anymore after SMART feature, as they apparently seem to be safely auto-fixed on demand?

Comment: I just discovered something interesting and posted it here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/501466/30352

Comment: @roaima found this https://superuser.com/questions/693003/badblocks-vs-smart-extended-self-test, thx!

Comment: mmm... I finally did smart check tests. The short and the long, both failed!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you wrote,

> The disk I want to check currently has 51 bad/pending sectors from smart data at gnome-disks. Do you mean that specifically looking for bad blocks is not really necessary anymore after SMART feature, as they apparently seem to be safely auto-fixed on demand?

Pending sectors are sectors that can't be read. When you next try to write to them, the disk firmware will automatically remap the new data to spare sectors. You don't need `badblocks` for this.

However, 51 sectors are a lot of sectors that have failed. You may find the disk can't remap all of them. With this many sectors it would be well worth checking the health of the drive and seriously considering replacing it.

Comment: by "checking the health of the drive" I guess it is the full "SMART check", I read it can take about 2.5hours, may be worth it. Btw, the funny part is that is says: "Disk is OK, 51 bad sectors", now how OK it is actually is the confusing part. I thought spare sectors were everything non allocated, or there is just a little bit like may be 100ss for 1TB HD? That HD is an old indeed. I see a 2TB HD is not pricey, I will consider buying a new one and throw all redundancy backups on this one :)

Comment: If it's to be used 24x7 (or thereabouts) consider a NAS-grade disk rather than the cheapest you can find.